# Bat Error "invalid number of parameters"

Tags: batch-file, backup, xcopy

I am trying to write a bat file to backup a folder on my work server (sometimes the server and backup server do not sync correctly and files go missing).

I have tried many different solutions and read a few different forums to try to resolve this, but I cannot seem to find anything.

```
@echo This will now create a new backup of S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14

@echo off

:: variables
set SRCFOLDER="S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14"
set DESTFOLDER="S:\Internal Auditor\2014\9 - Sept Backup"
set folder=%date:~5,2%-%date:~8,2%-%date:~0,4%
set backupcmd=xcopy /W /E /H /V /C /Z /I /F /J /R /Y

echo ######## PLEASE WAIT SYSTEM BACKINGUP SOME DATA########
xcopy %SRCFOLDER% %DESTFOLDER% %backupcmd%

echo !!!!!!!!BACKUP COMPLETED THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
@pause
```

Please help - I'm tired of losing files, and I don't want to have to manually backup files every day.

(The goal is the create a new folder with date & time every time it runs under the sub-folder "9 - September 14"{historical backup}).

***EDIT***
Ok - So I have another thread open for something that was different, but now my 2 questions have kinda merged together, so please look @ [New folder for every backup CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751668/new-folder-for-every-backup-cmd) and see if you could help...

Comment: You are using xcopy twice... thats why the "invalid number of parameters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `set backupcmd=/W /E /H /V /C /Z /I /F /J /R /Y`

instead of `set backupcmd=xcopy /W /E /H /V /C /Z /I /F /J /R /Y` . You have redundant xcopy in parameters.

**EDIT.** As far as I understood your comments you need a new folder like this `"S:\Internal Auditor\%date:~5,2%-%date:~8,2%-%date:~0,4%"`

so you can do this:

```
set SRCFOLDER="S:\Internal Auditor"
set "DESTFOLDER="S:\Internal Auditor\2014"
set "folder=%date:~5,2%-%date:~8,2%-%date:~0,4%"
md "%DESTFOLDER%\%folder%" >nul 2>&1
set "backupcmd=/W /E /H /V /C /Z /I /F /J /R /Y"
echo ######## PLEASE WAIT SYSTEM BACKINGUP SOME DATA########
xcopy "%SRCFOLDER%\%folder%" "%DESTFOLDER%\%folder%" %backupcmd%

echo !!!!!!!!BACKUP COMPLETED THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: This worked! Also, it is supposed to make a new folder with each backup, which it did not - Any suggestions for that? Do I need to put %folder% in w/ the 'xcopy' line?

Comment: You can include "md new_folder" before xcopy. Now im writing from my phone and cant help you more @Bcarr91

Comment: Thank you - I am having issues with md new_folder, so I will search for a thread and/or post a new one.

Comment: This will now create a new backup of S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14
Access is denied.
Error occurred while processing: S:\Internal.
A subdirectory or file Auditor\2014\9 already exists.
Error occurred while processing: Auditor\2014\9.
A subdirectory or file - already exists.
Error occurred while processing: -.
A subdirectory or file Sept already exists.
Error occurred while processing: Sept.
|
|
|
Invalid number of parameters

I'm about to just give up... lol

Answer (score 0):

After you enter the required source and destination path try this code..

```
set xcopy=xcopy //switches as per your requirement
set Folder=%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-4,4%
mkdir %DESTPATH%\%Folder%
pause
%xcopy% %SOURCEPATH% %DESTPATH%\%Folder%
pause
```