# New folder for every backup CMD

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, backup, xcopy

I am trying to get a batch going to backup a folder on a work server. (Please see attached link)
[Bat Error "invalid number of parameters"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750107/bat-error-invalid-number-of-parameters)

Long story short - I need the script to name a new folder for each backup, which "md new_folder" was suggested, but I cannot seem to get the context or how to place it into the code.

```
@echo This will now create a new backup of S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14

@echo off

:: variables
set SRCFOLDER="S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14"
set DESTFOLDER="S:\Internal Auditor\2014\9 - Sept Backup"
set folder=%date:~5,2%-%date:~8,2%-%date:~0,4%
set backupcmd=/W /E /H /V /C /Z /I /F /J /R /Y

echo ######## PLEASE WAIT SYSTEM BACKINGUP SOME DATA########
"md new_folder" xcopy %SRCFOLDER% %DESTFOLDER% %backupcmd%

echo !!!!!!!!BACKUP COMPLETED THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
@pause
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

----------***EDIT:***
    I tried a line of code that slowly got me closer:----------

```
@echo This will now create a new backup of S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14

@echo off

:: variables
set SRCFOLDER="S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14"
set DESTFOLDER="S:\Internal Auditor\2014\9 - Sept Backup"
set folder=%date:~5,2%-%date:~8,2%-%date:~0,4%
md "%DESTFOLDER%\%folder%"
set backupcmd=/W /E /H /V /C /Z /I /F /J /R /Y

echo ######## PLEASE WAIT SYSTEM BACKING UP SOME DATA########
xcopy %SRCFOLDER% "%DESTFOLDER%\%folder%" %backupcmd%

echo !!!!!!!!BACKUP COMPLETED THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
@pause
```

**BUT - I am getting the following output:**

```
This will now create a new backup of S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14
Access is denied.
Error occurred while processing: S:\Internal.
A subdirectory or file Auditor\2014\9 already exists.
Error occurred while processing: Auditor\2014\9.
A subdirectory or file - already exists.
Error occurred while processing: -.
A subdirectory or file Sept already exists.
Error occurred while processing: Sept.
A subdirectory or file Backup\9/-9/-Tue  already exists.
Error occurred while processing: Backup\9/-9/-Tue .
######## PLEASE WAIT SYSTEM BACKING UP SOME DATA########
Invalid number of parameters
!!!!!!!!BACKUP COMPLETED THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

----------***EDIT 2: I tried a line of code that slowly got me closer:----------***

I have followed the suggestions and some things I found online, and now I am to the point where I am getting a few errors:

```
md "S:\Internal Auditor\~\09/12/2014"
A subdirectory or file S:\Internal Auditor\~\09/12/2014 already exists.
```

And:

```
xcopy "S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14 S:\Internal Auditor\2014\9 - Sept Backup\09/12/2014
/W /E /H /V /C /Z /I /F /J /R /Y /D
File not found - 09/12/2014 /W /E /H /V /C /Z /I /F /J /R /Y /D
```

***This is my code:***

```
@echo This will now create a new backup of S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14
Rem Backup 9 - September 14

@echo

:: variables
set "SRCFOLDER=S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14"
set "DESTFOLDER=S:\Internal Auditor\2014\9 - Sept Backup"
set folder=%date:~4%
md "%DESTFOLDER%\%folder%"
set backupcmd=/W /E /H /V /C /Z /I /F /J /R /Y /D


@echo ######## PLEASE WAIT SYSTEM BACKING UP SOME DATA########

xcopy "%SRCFOLDER% %DESTFOLDER%\%folder% %backupcmd%"

@echo !!!!!!!!BACKUP COMPLETED THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
@pause
```

Also, when I run the code, it makes a new directory ~\09\12\2014 instead of the desired ~\09/12/2014.
Clarification:
It makes 3 new subdirectories instead of one new subdirectory.

Comment: do not turn `echo off`, so you will be able to see how your batch file is parsed. you'll see that you have issues with your quotes (eg. you define your DESTDIR including the quotes, but then you surround it with another pair at the `md` line and xcopy

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to turn off 'echo' - It has helped me tremendously...

Comment: you are enclosing all xcopy parameters in quotes, instead of only the two paths, individually. also, you can't have / in pathnames, that's illegal.

Comment: the "set folder=%date:~4% puts the '/' by default...
Why would it do that if it's illegal?

Comment: because dos isn't psychic. it doesn't know that you'll be using that string as a folder name.

Comment: Haha - Ok - So how would I correct it to not use '/'?
Also -

Comment: EDIT:

Haha - Ok - So how would I correct it to not use '/'?
Also -

I keep getting an error "Invalid number of parameters" error on the string:

    xcopy %SRCFOLDER% %DESTFOLDER%\%folder% %backupcmd%

Answer (score 0):

Okay let's see what you're doing. Your variable `folder` is being set based on your local settings for a short date, which for me shows e.g. `Tue 09/09/2014` so your `%date:~0,4%` would be `Tue`.  Use the echo command to be sure you're getting what you want:

```
echo %date:~5,2%-%date:~8,2%-%date:~0,4%
```

But let's assume for now you already figured that out and `%folder%` contains what you want it to.  This is two commands on a line, which won't work at best at at worst is going to create a bunch of folders you didn't expect:

```
"md new_folder" xcopy %SRCFOLDER% %DESTFOLDER% %backupcmd%
```

You want to split that into 2 lines, and you want to use your new date-based folder name as part of the destination, I'm sure.  So this will do that:

```
md "%DESTFOLDER%\%folder%"
```

and then to copy you'd need to include `\%folder%` in your destination:

```
xcopy %SRCFOLDER% %DESTFOLDER%\%folder% %backupcmd%
```

But I think, and I know I shouldn't ask for clarification but perhaps if I'm wrong you should clarify what you need a bit more in your question, you really want that `S:\Internal Auditor\2014\9 - Sept Backup` to be `S:\Internal Auditor\` plus the value in `%folder%` and not having the date the way it is in that path.

Suggestion:  Make the `%folder%` variable to be `yyyy-mm-dd` format such as 2014-09-09 so it's sortable, and use that in your destination.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the echo %date - I did find a folder I did not expect - on my Desktop. XD

And to clarify:
"S:\~\9 - September 14" is the original folder
I need the backup to copy the contents of above to:
"S:\~\9 - Sept Backup", but when it does this, I need it to make a new folder in the backup folder with the date and time as the Folder Name.

Also:
Can I do:
set folder=%date: yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: No, you have to parse out the parts of the date like you did but with attention to what the sections are.  There are no doubt dozens of examples on this site.  For my `Wed 09/10/2014` result fort today (US standard format) it would be `set folder=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%` to get `2014-10-09`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. There are some errors:

```
set SRCFOLDER="S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14"
set DESTFOLDER="S:\Internal Auditor\2014\9 - Sept Backup"
```

Must be (safe method, adding first quote at start of `SRCFOLDER` and `DESTFOLDER`):

```
set "SRCFOLDER=S:\Internal Auditor\9 - September 14"
set "DESTFOLDER=S:\Internal Auditor\2014\9 - Sept Backup"
```